# Why do people still do traditional jobs to earn money?

Tags: income

If [PweDiePie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PewDiePie) earns [$500000 per month](https://gamequitters.com/pewdiepie-net-worth/), why do people still in 2020 do demanding/[draining](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYNAyXg3VCc)/[volatile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eefUpzSnmcw) corporate jobs, life-threatening military/[spy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8FtstMvYH4)/[mercenary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5ms-XZ-Vdg) jobs, [horrible teaching jobs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEyF8qwq_58), and so on to earn money?

if there are ways to earn money by not draining body and soul, why do people still do those horrible or high-stakes jobs?

Comment: Are you asking why people don't make YouTube videos for a living instead of working at a job?

Comment: @TannerSwett, I am asking, if there are ways to earn money by not draining my soul and health, why do people still do that?

Comment: How do you know streaming doesn't drain your soul and health?

Comment: If everyone can do it, it's not valuable.

Comment: Bear in mind that those numbers are simply wild guesses about what he makes, he's never released an audited financial statement. And why would he? His whole presence is based on creating buzz and clickbait articles claiming he makes $5000000 a month just feed the buzz.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant: He's a Swede. Just call the tax authority if you want the real number.

Comment: @MSalters which only serves to increase my suspicion since the linked articles didn't do that. They relied on "guesstimates" based on the number of views.

Comment: Why do people take office or manual labor jobs instead of becoming a rockstar?

Comment: Are you talking about the 3rd world or the 1st? Your question shows a total alienation from reality, someone has to grow the food you eat while watching PweDiePie videos...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To earn money like PewDiePie, you have to be very talented (I've never seen his videos so I'll give him the benefit of the doubt) and/or very lucky.

Most people are not very talented and not very lucky so they unfortunately have to take regular jobs.

If you work hard, then you can increase your skills and get a more satisfying job (or maybe start your own business which can be extremely satisfying).  Unfortunately, you can't increase your luck.

Comment: “Chance favors the prepared mind.” You can’t increase your luck, but you can improve your ability to take advantage of it.

Comment: @PeterK. - I've written a book about that, only $50, that will surely make you rich within a year.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I can't buy it, I spend my last $50 on a bridge in Brooklyn.